# No viable overloaded "=" in qt

Tags: qt

I wrote the code below, but I get a notification saying No viable overloaded "=".

(Note that the list id contains some strings)

```
QList<QString>id;
QList<int>::iterator iter;
iter = std::find(logid.begin(), logid.end(), id);
```

Comment: And how and where is declared `logid`? `id` is another problem, it has very little sense that you declare it as a `QList<QString>`. You may be looking for an `int` among a list of integers or you are looking for a `QString` in a list of strings.

Comment: It would be better if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that when compiled produces only the error message that youo are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using the `std::find` function incorrectly. You are also trying to find inside a list another list.

Try this:

```
#include <QtDebug>

QList<int> logid = {1, 2, 3};
QList<QString> ids = {"2", "5"};
for (const auto &id : ids) {
    auto it = std::find_if(logid.begin(), logid.end(), [&](const int x) {
        return x == id.toInt();
    });

    if (it != logid.end()) {
        // Valid item
        qDebug() << "Address" << &it;
        qDebug() << "Value" << *it;
    }
}
```

Note: since **ids** is a `List` of `QString`, you need to convert it to int.